# Extraer datos de un archivo xml en c#

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo un archivo xml del cual quiero extraer los conceptos de una factura

```
<cfdi:Conceptos>
  <cfdi:Concepto importe="13000.00" valorUnitario="13000.00" descripcion="Servicio profesional médico" unidad="No Aplica" cantidad="1" />
  <cfdi:Concepto importe="90.000" valorUnitario="90.000" descripcion="Servicio profesional médico" unidad="No Aplica" cantidad="1" />
</dfdi:Conceptos>
```

Para esto utilizo el siguiente código:

```
List<object[]> listaConceptos = new List<object[]>();
var conceptos = from c in doc.Descendants()
                where c.Name.LocalName == "Conceptos"
                select c.Elements();

foreach (var item in conceptos)
{
    object[] dato = new object[5];
    dato[0] = item.Attributes("cantidad").First().Value;
    dato[1] = item.Attributes("unidad").First().Value;
    dato[2] = item.Attributes("descripcion").First().Value;
    dato[3] = item.Attributes("valorUnitario").First().Value;
    dato[4] = item.Attributes("importe").First().Value;

    listaConceptos.Add(dato);
}
```

Pero solo me funciona si es un solo concepto, porque únicamente me guarda el primer concepto en el arreglo y los demás ya no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La expresion:

```
from c in doc.Descendants()
where c.Name.LocalName == "Conceptos"
select c.Elements();
```

Returna una colecion de colecciones de `XElement` o `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>`. En otras palabras esto:

```
 IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>> conceptos = from c in doc.Descendants()
                            where c.Name.LocalName == "Conceptos"
                            select c.Elements();
```

Por lo tanto tienes 2 opciones:

Recorres la coleccion de colecciones para leer los datos. Osea, haces un `foreach` y por cada elemento haces otro foreach para recorrer el elemento actual del primer foreach(un foreach dentro de otro):

```
List<object[]> listaConceptos = new List<object[]>();
            var conceptos = from c in doc.Descendants()
                            where c.Name.LocalName == "Conceptos"
                            select c.Elements();

            foreach (IEnumerable<XElement> item in conceptos)
            {
                foreach (var conceptoXML in item)
                {
                    object[] dato = new object[5];
                    dato[0] = conceptoXML.Attribute("cantidad").Value;
                    dato[1] = conceptoXML.Attribute("unidad").Value;
                    dato[2] = conceptoXML.Attribute("descripcion").Value;
                    dato[3] = conceptoXML.Attribute("valorUnitario").Value;
                    dato[4] = conceptoXML.Attribute("importe").Value;

                    listaConceptos.Add(dato);
                }
            }
```

O obtienes el primer resultado de la coleccion de la expresion con el metodo `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
List<object[]> listaConceptos = new List<object[]>();
            IEnumerable<XElement> conceptos = (from c in doc.Descendants()
                            where c.Name.LocalName == "Conceptos"
                            select c.Elements())
                            .FirstOrDefault(); // retornar solo el primer resultado de la coleccion de colecciones de XElement


            foreach (XElement conceptoXML in conceptos)
            {

                    object[] dato = new object[5];
                    dato[0] = conceptoXML.Attribute("cantidad").Value;
                    dato[1] = conceptoXML.Attribute("unidad").Value;
                    dato[2] = conceptoXML.Attribute("descripcion").Value;
                    dato[3] = conceptoXML.Attribute("valorUnitario").Value;
                    dato[4] = conceptoXML.Attribute("importe").Value;

                    listaConceptos.Add(dato);

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es muy simple, en tu `foreach` necesitas cambiar:

```
foreach (var item in conceptos)
```

Por esto:

```
foreach (var item in conceptos.ElementAt(0))
```

Esto signfica que ya tienes el nodo, ahora simplemente requieres acceder a los elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí una manera:

Con la siguiente instrucción, obtienes todos los elementos de xml que sean concepto, al ponerle al final toList los obtienes en una lista

```
List<XElement> li = doc.Descendants("Concepto").ToList();
```

En la siguiente instrucción, recorres la lista de 'conceptos' y obtienes los atributos por cada concepto y los asignas a tu objeto

```
List<object[]> listaConceptos = new List<object[]>();
foreach(var item in li)
{
    object[] dato = new object[5];

    dato[0] = item.Attribute("cantidad").Value;
    dato[1] = item.Attribute("unidad").Value;
    dato[2] = item.Attribute("descripcion").Value;
    dato[3] = item.Attribute("valorUnitario").Value;
    dato[4] = item.Attribute("importe").Value;

    listaConceptos.Add(dato);
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes dar una pequeña explicación a tu respuesta? :)